# How to map values in a dataframe to a key with values specific to each column?

Tags: r

This is a little complicated to explain in words, so I'll just give you a dummy version of my data.

```
#dummy data for help
col.1<-c(1,2,2,1,1)
col.2<-c(2,1,3,1,2)
col.3<-c(2,4,1,1,2)
df<-data.frame(col.1,col.2,col.3)
key<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")
names(key)<-c("col.1_1","col.1_2",
              "col.2_1","col.2_2","col.2_3",
              "col.3_1","col.3_2","col.3_3","col.3_4")
```

`> key`

```
col.1_1 col.1_2 col.2_1 col.2_2 col.2_3 col.3_1 col.3_2 col.3_3 col.3_4 
    "A"     "B"     "C"     "D"     "E"     "F"     "G"     "H"     "I"
```

`> df`

```
  col.1 col.2 col.3
1     1     2     2
2     2     1     4
3     2     3     1
4     1     1     1
5     1     2     2
```

If the name of an item in `key` is `col.x_y`, this should be interpreted to mean that it should correspond to all values `y` in column `df$col.x`. Hence there are as many elements in `key` as there are unique value-column pairs in `df`.

My end goal is to replace all `y`s in `df$col.x` with the value of `col.x_y` in `key`.

For example, since `col.2_3` is `E`, ALL 3s in `df$col.2` -- and ONLY in `df$col.2` -- should be replaced with `E`.

So I want to end up with:

`> df`

```
   col.1  col.2  col.3
1    "A"    "D"    "G"
2    "B"    "C"    "I"
3    "B"    "E"    "F"
4    "A"    "C"    "F"
5    "A"    "D"    "G"
```

Importantly, though, **my real `key` is a named numeric list, and the values are essentially random**; I just used ordered letters for the simplicity of the example.

The problem I keep running into is that I can't figure out how to refer to a variable column name. `df$variable_name` doesn't seem to work in any of the approaches I've tried, and I can't think of a way around it.

Here are a couple of ideas I've come up with:

```
recodeY<- function(.x,.y) {
  split_name<-strsplit(.y, split="_")
  score<-split_name[2]
  column_name<-split_name[1]
  gsub(column_name=score, .x, df)
}
library(purrr)
map2(key, names(key), recodeY)
```

Not sure if this was the version that ran successfully, but when it did, it came up with 0 values in the output.

This one is just a mess:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  for(j in 1:length(key)) {
    col_name<-colnames(df[i])
    split_name<-unlist(strsplit(names(j), split="_"))
    item_name<-split_name[1]
    if(col_name==item_name){
      score<-split_name[2]
      str_replace(i, ?, ?) #lost track of what I was doing, never done for loops before
      #gsub(i, j, finalCYOA2$i) couldn't get gsub or sub to work, ran into the same problem
    }
  }
}
```

Any advice on how to proceed? I'd say I'm of intermediate skill with R, but I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge since I self-taught.

EDIT: Since one of the potential solutions was breaking on my real data, here's a more naturalistic example:

```
col.1A<-c(NA,2,2,1,1)
col.2A<-c(2,1,3,1,NA)
col.2A.1<-c(2,4,NA,1,3)
df<-data.frame(col.1A,col.2A,col.2A.1)
key<-c(1.111,1.222,
       2.111,2.222,2.333,
       3.111,3.222,3.333,3.444)
names(key)<-c("col.1A_1","col.1A_2",
              "col.2A_1","col.2A_2","col.2A_3",
              "col.2A.1_1","col.2A.1_2","col.2A.1_3","col.2A.1_4")
```

`key`

```
  col.1A_1   col.1A_2   col.2A_1   col.2A_2   col.2A_3 col.2A.1_1 col.2A.1_2 col.2A.1_3 col.2A.1_4 
     1.111      1.222      2.111      2.222      2.333      3.111      3.222      3.333      3.444
```

`df`

```
  col.1A col.2A col.2A.1
1     NA      2        2
2      2      1        4
3      2      3       NA
4      1      1        1
5      1     NA        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` column names and values together, and `match`:

```
df[] <- key[match( paste(names(df)[col(df)], unlist(df), sep="_"), names(key) )]
df

#  col.1 col.2 col.3
#1     A     D     G
#2     B     C     I
#3     B     E     F
#4     A     C     F
#5     A     D     G
```

Comment: This is working perfectly when I apply it to the dummy data, but for some reason it's breaking in specific cases in the real data when the column is something like `col.1A.1`.  I tried making the dummy data closer in format to the real data (changed `key` to numbers with decimals, added `NA`s to `df`, changed col names to `col.1A`, `col.2A`, and `col.2A.1`) but none of these changes are breaking the code in the same way it's getting broken in the real data. Any idea what could be going on...? 

For reference, here are some examples from my real data:

Comment: [Real column names of `df`]: CYOA.01A CYOA.01B CYOA.01C CYOA.01D CYOA.02A CYOA.02A.1 CYOA.02B CYOA.02C CYOA.02C.1 ...


[Real names of `key` elements]: CYOA.01A_1 CYOA.01A_2 CYOA.01A_3 CYOA.01A_4 CYOA.01A_5 CYOA.01B_1 ...


[Real values of `key` elements]:  1.162698   1.451720   1.342593   2.193783   2.845238   1.114074 ...

As far as I can tell, the only difference is number of columsn/elements.

Comment: If your real data has numeric values like 1.162698 then there's a good chance it will break because the values and the names won't match exactly, because the number is actually stored with more precision than shown.

Comment: I tried extending the dummy `key` to include 10 decimal places, and the dummy example still works fine. I'm also not sure why that would cause only certain columns (the ones with an extra period and digit at the end of the name) to fail, while the other columns work perfectly...

Comment: What are the numbers in df though? Try breaking out the parts of the code and check the paste vs the names(key) parts - they need to be exactly the same for the code to match them up.

Comment: WOW I feel stupid: there are actually holes in my real version of `key`, so the problem is those values in `df` just don't have referents. Thank you so much because I think your solution will work perfectly when I fix this problem!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option in `tidyverse`.  Reshape the 'key' to a long format data with `pivot_longer`.  Then loop `across` the columns of 'df', extract the values from the corresponding column names and replace by `match`ing the values with the 'grp' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
new <- key %>%
      as.data.frame.list %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
        names_sep="_")
 df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ new[[cur_column()]][match(., new$grp)]))
```

-output

```
#   col.1 col.2 col.3
#1     A     D     G
#2     B     C     I
#3     B     E     F
#4     A     C     F
#5     A     D     G
```

---

or another option is to loop `across` the columns of data, create the names of the 'key' by pasting the column name with the value and extract the 'key' based on the name

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ key[str_c(cur_column(), "_", .)]))
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
new <- transform(stack(key), grp = as.integer(sub(".*_", "", ind)), 
    ind = sub("_.*", "", ind))
df[] <- Map(function(x, y) y$values[match(x, y$grp)], df, split(new[-2], new$ind))
```

#### Update

Using the new example, it works well

```
df %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ key[str_c(cur_column(), "_", .)]))
#  col.1A col.2A col.2A.1
#1     NA  2.222    3.222
#2  1.222  2.111    3.444
#3  1.222  2.333       NA
#4  1.111  2.111    3.111
#5  1.111     NA    3.333
```

---

Or the one with `base R`

```
new <- transform(stack(key), grp = as.integer(sub(".*_", "", ind)), 
    ind = sub("_.*", "", ind))
df[] <- Map(function(x, y) y$values[match(x, y$grp)], df, split(new[-2], new$ind))
df
#  col.1A col.2A col.2A.1
#1     NA  2.222    3.222
#2  1.222  2.111    3.444
#3  1.222  2.333       NA
#4  1.111  2.111    3.111
#5  1.111     NA    3.333
```

---

Or with `pivot_longer`

```
new <- key %>%
      as.data.frame.list %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", 'grp'), 
        names_sep="_")
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ new[[cur_column()]][match(., new$grp)]))
#  col.1A col.2A col.2A.1
#1     NA  2.222    3.222
#2  1.222  2.111    3.444
#3  1.222  2.333       NA
#4  1.111  2.111    3.111
#5  1.111     NA    3.333
```

Comment: Your `base r` solution worked on my more naturalistic example (see edited portion of post above); however, when I apply it to my real data, I get `Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter`

Comment: I'm getting an error on the dummy data with the first one. On `pivot_longer`, I get `Error: `cols` must select at least one column.` With the second one, on `mutate(across(everything...` I get `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  row names contain missing values`. I was just now looking up how to address NAs with that function but haven't found it yet.

Comment: I didn't find any error in any of the solutions.  All of them are working fine for me.